Can reference letters be sent in after the application due date? If so, how late it can be?
I am applying for Ph.D. programs for fall 2025. I found that most universities' application deadlines are before the end of the 2024 fall semester (or slightly later). Does that mean that it is impossible for me to seek reference letters from the courses I take this fall? Is it possible to deliver the letters later than the deadline of the application?

This may strongly depend on the country and perhaps institution. However, I would generally assume a deadline is a deadline, especially for competitive applications. Note that this is different from whether you can get recommendations letters for the fall semester - if you stand out from your peers, you will stand out long before the end of the semester.

Is there a reason a professor cannot write a letter for you while the course is ongoing?  (One possible reason would be that the professor has no contact with you and no information about your performance other than the final exam, but in that case, the letter is going to be fairly uninformative no matter what - yes this disadvantages students coming from cultures where professors have little contact with students.)

united-states
I have seen applications where the deadline for letters is after the due date for the applicant. This may be more or less common in your field.
I have never been on an admissions committee, but I have heard that some applications will informally accept letters late because they are professors too, and may need a similar courtesy later. However, it is impossible to predict if the programs you are applying to include this courtesy if they don't mention it.
Nevertheless, this is all on the order of a week or two. If applications are due Nov. 1, then no, you don't have time to finish fall semester before asking that professor to write you a letter.
You may need to take this into consideration when asking someone to write you a letter. You are correct that if you ask a month before an Oct. 15 deadline, a professor may not be willing to write you a letter based on a few weeks of work.
In short, assume the posted deadline is a deadline, and take it into consideration when selecting letter-writers.
An aside, I know many faculty whose standard for who they write a letter for is more than a single class.
